# Django ListView which includes forms

Tags: python, django

Lately I am moving from method based views to the class based views in Django.

I feel that I couldn't find a good solution to use ListView together with forms.

Below code in new view works but pagination does not work.

Where I am doing wrong?
Also, what do you think new view? Is there another and cleaner way to do that?

Old method based view:

```
def list_orders(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = billing_forms.OrdersForm(request.POST)
        object_list = orders.list_orders_by_date(
            owner=request.user,
            year=form.data.get('year'),
            month=form.data.get('month')
        )
    else:
        form = billing_forms.OrdersForm()
        object_list = billing_orders.list_orders(owner=request.user)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(objects_list, 10)
    try:
        object_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        object_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        object_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return shortcuts.render(request, 'billing/orders.html', {
        'object_list': object_list,
        'form': form,
    })
```

New class based view:

```
class OrdersListView(ListView, BaseLoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'billing/orders.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = billing_forms.OrdersForm()
        object_list = billing_orders.list_orders(owner=request.user)
        return shortcuts.render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'object_list': object_list})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = billing_forms.OrdersForm(request.POST)
        object_list = billing_orders.list_orders_by_date(
            owner=request.user,
            year=form.data.get('year'),
            month=form.data.get('month'),
        )
        return shortcuts.render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'object_list': object_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` handles the pagination for you. In your case, it does not, since you are overriding the `get` method. You can use `get_queryset` method to provide queryset, there is no need to rewrite the whole `get` method:

```
class OrdersListView(ListView, BaseLoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'billing/orders.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    form_class = billing_forms.OrdersForm
    model = Order

    def get_queryset(self):
        return billing_orders.list_orders(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I know this but what I want to do is returning different queryset when request is POST. and return form back too of course.
when i do POST call, I need to query in db with year and month and whatever I get as response should be also paginated. Having issues with pagination so far.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you don't need to add a post method but only use GET method and filter the query:
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

```
class OrdersListView(ListView, BaseLoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'billing/orders.html'
    model = billing_orders
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        #handle you queryset
        query = billing_orders.list_orders(owner=request.user)

        if self.request.GET.get("year", None) != None:
            return query.filter(year=self.request.GET.get("year"))
        else:
            return query
```

[here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/) you can learn more about class base view

Comment: it returns 405 like this as post is not allowed

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add post method, I edited my answer.now you can handle a form.

Comment: thanks for help but with post, it just returns all queryset objects like get method. not, the object_list from form_valid method

Comment: Do you want to use this form to filter the list?

Comment: yes, i want to filter the list and want to have pagination on filtered list as well

Comment: I updated my answer, you can filter only using get method.